# python mapreduce - Skipping the first line of the .csv in mapper

Tags: python, csv, hadoop, mapreduce, mrjob

I am trying to do mapreduce in python and my csv file looks like below,

```
    trip_id taxi_id pickup_time dropoff_time ... total
0   20117   2455.0  2013-05-05   09:45:00         50.44
1   44691   1779.0  2013-06-24   11:30:00         66.78
```

and my codes are,

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from mrjob.job import MRJob

class MRCount(MRJob):

def mapper(self, _, line):
    datarow = line.replace(' ','').replace('N/A','').split(',')
    trip_id = datarow[0]
    total = datarow[14]
    total = np.float(total)
    yield ((trip_id), (total))
```

Since my code pass all lines to mapper, so it starts with the string line ( index) but I want to do play with total which is float so when I run the file, it get an error

```
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'generator'
```

How can I skip the first line in csv file when processing mapper function?

Comment: In general it makes no sense to have the only yield as the last line of a function with no loops.  What are you doing with `mapper`?

Comment: @StephenRauch What if it is the last line of a loop body inside the function :)

Comment: @StephenRauch I want to match trip_id and total in every line in csv file, I have another command line to pass line by line from csv file, python3 test.py --jobconf mapreduce.job.reduces=1 CSTaxiTrips.csv. Do I have to open csv file in the mapper function and use next() function to skip first line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure exactly what content 'line' has. A simple answer to your problem is to just try/except the float.

```
def mapper(self, _, line):
    datarow = line.replace(' ','').replace('N/A','').split(',')
    trip_id = datarow[0]
    total = datarow[14]
    try:
        total = np.float(total)
    except TypeError:
        print("skipping line with value", datarow[14])
    else:
        yield ((trip_id), (total))
```

Comment: Line has  content     (line 1) trip_id taxi_id pickup_time dropoff_time ... total

(line 2) 0   20117   2455.0  2013-05-05   09:45:00         50.44

(line 3)1   44691   1779.0  2013-06-24   11:30:00         66.78

and still it gives me the error, I think everytime I read the lines, it convert to every values to string.